# Dividing variables giving false zero result

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code which is taking some inputs from a userform and then entering them into my spreadsheet, nothing tricky. The issue is 2 of my pieces of data, which are the result of dividing 2 other variables, always give a result of zero regardless of what the true answer should be. But if I go into the spreadsheet itself and do the calculations using the same inputs it works exactly as I need. The variables causing me grief are "rRate" and "pRate". Is there an issue with my variable declarations or something else entirely?

```
Dim rRate As Long
Dim sTime As Date
Dim fTime As Date
Dim tTime As Date
Dim pRate As Long
Dim Rejects As Long
Dim tProd As Long

Rejects = frmProduction.lblTotalRejects.Caption
tProd = frmProduction.lblTotal.Caption

rRate = Rejects / tProd 'msgbox gives 0

sTime = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, "B")
fTime = Now
tTime = fTime - sTime

pRate = tTime / tProd 'msgbox gives 0

ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, "O") = Rejects
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, "P") = tProd
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, "AH") = Format(rRate, Percent) 'not working
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, "AI") = Format(tTime, "h:mm")
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, "AL") = Format(pRate, "h:mm:ss") 'not working
```

Comment: For rRate to be 0, I wonder if the variable Rejects being assigned a value correctly?

Comment: Rejects gets input into the spreadsheet too and it is the correct value. Same with tProd. When I go into the spreadsheet and divide those two cells I get the correct answer

Comment: Declare them `As Double` instead of `As Long`. As they're the result of division, any decimal places they have will be discarded if you declare them `As Long`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is variable declaration, as you guessed.

`rRate` and `pRate` both are the result of division: `rRate = Rejects / tProd` and `pRate = tTime / tProd`. Any decimal places that result will be silently discarded since the variables are declared `As Long`.

For example, if you expect `rRate` to be 0.475, if declared `As Long` the decimal places will be discarded, it will equal 0, and your `msgBox` will return 0. Instead, you can declare them `As Double`.

See the [Long](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/long-data-type) vs [Double](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/double-data-type) data types for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of closing this question here is the now working code. Thanks BigBen for the input.

```
Dim rRate As Double
Dim sTime As Date
Dim fTime As Date
Dim tTime As Date
Dim pRate As Double
Dim Rejects As Long
Dim tProd As Long

Rejects = frmProduction.lblTotalRejects.Caption
tProd = frmProduction.lblTotal.Caption

rRate = Rejects / tProd

sTime = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, "B")
fTime = Now
tTime = fTime - sTime

pRate = tTime / tProd

ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, "AH") = Format(rRate, Percent)
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, "AL") = Format(pRate, "h:mm:ss")
```